# 2 KeepassXC versions installed

Tags: upgrade, uninstall, keepassxc

A year ago, I installed KeepassXC to manage my passwords. I don't remember I installed though.
Today I went on the official web page to check if new versions were available and found that there were upgrades available.
When I tried to upgrade it

`sudo apt-get install --only-upgrade keepassxc`

I got

```
E: Unable to locate package keepassxc
```

So I installed it though the repository but I have now 2 keepassxc installations.

My question is how do I remove the old version without also removing the newest one.

Here are the answers to the requests in the comments below:

```
$ snap list
Name                  Version          Rev   Tracking  Publisher       Notes
core                  16-2.42.1        8039  stable    canonical✓      core
core18                0.1              19    stable    canonical✓      base
gtk-common-themes     0.1-16-g2287c87  1198  stable    canonical✓      -
htmldoc               1.9.7            283   stable    michaelrsweet   -
keepassxc             2.3.4            49    stable    keepassxreboot  -
nmap                  7.12SVN-0.6      29    stable    maxiberta       -
notepad-plus-plus     7.6.4            193   stable    mmtrt           -
shotcut               19.10.20         55    stable    meltytech✓      classic
simplescreenrecorder  0.1              1     stable    xiaoguo         -
skype                 8.30.0.50        54    stable    skype✓          classic
slack                 4.1.2            19    stable    slack✓          classic
stellarium-plars      0.18.1           29    stable    pwlars          -
wine-platform         3.0.4-4.0        88    stable    mmtrt           -


dpkg -l keepass*
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name           Version      Architecture Description
+++-==============-============-============-=================================
ii  keepassxc      2.5.1-0ppa1~ amd64        KeePass Cross-Platform Community 
un  keepassxc-beta <none>       <none>       (no description available)
```

Regards

Comment: Edit your question and show me `snap list` and `dpkg -l keepass*`.

Comment: Make sure to notify the user that you've replied to their request for more information, by sending a comment... in my case... starting with @heynnema... otherwise I'll have no notification that you've responded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have keepassxc installed twice.

1. snap install as version 2.3.4
2. deb install as version 2.5.1

You need to remove the older snap version.

`sudo snap remove keepassxc`